# Проблема с генерацией ссылки для смены пароля пользователя

Tags: python, flask

В учебных целях разрабатываю веб-приложение, в данный момент пытаюсь реализовать функцию по сбросу пароля через ссылку отправленную на email. Генерирую ссылку с помощью url_for и столкнулся с проблемой что он создает ссылку вставляя 'localhost' вместо сервера гитхаба на котором я запускаю приложение (не уверен что правильно выразился). вопрос как мне заменить этот 'localhost' на необходимые мне данные, заранее спасибо

```
        db_user = db.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = (?)", email)
        token = get_reset_password_token(db_user[0]['ID'])
        message = Message("хххх", recipients=[email])
        url = url_for('reset_password', token=token, _external=True)
        message.body = render_template("/reset_password.txt", url=url)
        mail.send(message)
        flash("ххх")
        return render_template("login.html")
    else:
        return render_template("сhange_password.html")

@app.route('/reset_password/<token>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def reset_password(token):
    if request.method == "POST":
        id = verify_reset_password_token(token)
        if not id:
            return redirect("/")
```

По итогу в письме получаю:
http://localhost/reset_password/eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJyZXNldF9wYXNzd29yZCI6MSwiZXhwIjoxNjUyMDAwODczLjUwMzQ5NDV9.g178uD02_3o65_f...

Comment: Прописать в настройках Flask https://stackoverflow.com/a/44825269

Comment: @andreymal, спасибо. Пробовал, возможно делаю что-то не так, но мое приложение вообще перестает работать и получаю ошибку: `/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py:1781: UserWarning: Current server name 'localhost' doesn't match configured server name 'lytvynov-kostiantyn-code.......'`